# QT QSystemTrayIcon context menu remains active when focus is lost

Tags: qt

I have implemented a QSystemTrayIcon in Qt with a context menu. The context menu automatically shows when the icon in the taskbar is right clicked, and also disappears appropriately when focus is lost.

However I have also connected the activated signal of the QSystemTrayIcon to a function that will show the context menu. This works fine in Ubuntu, but on Windows 7 the context menu shows, but does not disappear when focus is lost. I have tried the following ways of showing :

trayIconMenu->exec(QCursor::pos()); // shows in proper location, but doesn't disappear
 trayIconMenu->popup(QCursor::pos()); // same as exec()
 trayIconMenu->show(); // shows in incorrect location, and also doesn't disappear.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Thanks,

Gerry